# Working with configurations for python.. Preferably with Vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am facing a challenging scenario and being new to this, I am having trouble finding solution. there are two different folders in a server, one for testing and another for production and there needs to be particular configurations for respective scenarios. For an instance, the testing might have one configuration and the production has different one. SO what I want to do is, to either automate the configuration setting process based on which environment I am on or set an environment variable for it. Similarly, reading from config.py file is not a good option for this case. Is there any feature with VScode or any technique that would be suitable for my case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a Multi Root Workspace

Answer (score 0):

VScode 1.69 introduces a Setting Profile, will it fit in your case?
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_settings-profiles - Only in insiders yet